# mysql query for list all item with foreign key to location for stock

Tags: mysql

I have a database for managing multiple location stock of item.
I have 3 table like:

```
table_items
+----------+-------------+
| id_items |     name    |
+----------+-------------+
|  1       |   item 1    |
|  2       |   item 2    |
+----------+-------------+

table_location
+-------------+-------------+
| id_location |     name    |
+-------------+-------------+
|  1          |   location 1|
|  2          |   location 2|
+-------------+-------------+

table_stock
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id_location |  id_item  |   stock  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  1          |   1       |     3    |
|  1          |   2       |     0    |
|  2          |   1       |     1    |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Now how can I list all item in each location including item that doesn't exist there. for example i want to get item in location 2 so the result will be:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id_location |  id_item  |   stock  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  2          |   1       |     1    |
|  2          |   2       |   null   |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

or maybe there are any other way to do something like this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    i.`id_items`,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.id_location ELSE 2 END AS id_location,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.`stock` ELSE 0 END AS stock
  FROM
    table_items i 
    LEFT JOIN `table_stock` s 
      ON i.`id_items` = s.`id_items` 
  WHERE id_location = 2 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    i.`id_items`,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.id_location ELSE 2 END AS id_location,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.`stock` ELSE 0 END AS stock
  FROM
    table_items i 
    LEFT JOIN `table_stock` s 
      ON i.`id_items` = s.`id_items` 
  WHERE id_location != 2 
    AND i.id_items NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
      i.`id_items` 
    FROM
      table_items i 
      LEFT JOIN `table_stock` s 
    ON i.`id_items` = s.`id_items` 
    WHERE id_location = 2)) a
```

This next query is also able to produce the same result:

```
SELECT 
    i.`id_items`,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.id_location ELSE 2 END AS id_outlet,
    CASE WHEN s.id_location=2 THEN s.`qty` ELSE 0 END AS qty
  FROM
    table_items i 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_stock WHERE id_location=2) s 
      ON i.`id_items` = s.`id_items` 
  AND i.deleted=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.id_location, i.id_items, CASE WHEN sum(stock)=0 THEN null ELSE sum(stock) END AS stock
FROM table_items i LEFT JOIN table_stock s ON i.id_items=s.id_items
WHERE s.id_location=2
GROUP BY s.id_location, i.id_items;
```

This will give you location & item wise total stock. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think there are something missing here, the result is not like what i want like the example in my question. I need the **id_location** and the **id_item**, as for the qty its fine whether it got 0 or null

Comment: @inumaru As per I understand your requirement, I think this should work. This query will give you location and item wise total stock. If you need only location wise then you can remove id_items from projection & group by. Visa versa for the item wise also.

Comment: my requirement is for a list of all item in one location including the one that doesn't have stock in that location like my example. I have tried yours but I cannot get all item when I add `where id_location=2`

Comment: @inumaru If you want some filter then definitely you can add filters like location and items. If you add  `where id_location=2` it will give result location wise. I have just given main logic of your query. You can add filters based on your requirements. Just for reference I have updated my query with location filter.

Comment: Thanks, I found the query i want, and I got the exact result, but if you had any optimizing in mind I will check it.